# Error when using the numpy.where function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use the `numpy.where` function to check whether an element in an array is a certain string, like for example coffee and then returning a certain vector in places where this is true, and a different one in places where this is not the case.

However, I keep getting the error message saying operands could not be broadcast together with shapes `(4,)` `(1,3)` `(1,3)`.

Is there some other way I can do this without using for loops too much (the question explicitly says i should not use them)?

```
lst_1 = np.array(["dog", "dog1", "dog2", "dog3"])
a = np.where(lst_1 == "dog", [[1,0,0]], [[0,0,0]])
print(a)
```

Comment: The error message is explanatory, no? how are you going to index into (1,3) via (4, )?

Comment: Is your expected output `[[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`?

Comment: Check out broadcasting rules here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Yes, the expected output is [[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]].

Answer (score 1):

Can be done as a one-liner:

```py
out = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,0,0]])
idx = lst_1 == dog
out[idx.astype(np.int32)]
```

Alternatively avoiding casting:

```
np.take([[0,0,0],[1,0,0]], lst_1 == "dog", axis=0)
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer so people in the future can easily see that a solution was found if they have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without for loops, you can make use of lambda functions:

```
lst_1 = np.array(["dog", "dog1", "dog2", "dog3"])
a = list(map(lambda x: [1,0,0] if x=='dog' else [0,0,0], lst_1))

print(a)

> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```